# hibernate - get named query string without session

Tags: java, hibernate, session

Using a Session a named query can be retrieved like following:

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery(queryName);
```

But how can a named query be retrieved without using a session?

I am modifying the query-string dynamically and don't need a Session at that moment.

*The defined named-query is not changed*

Comment: `NamedQuery` can't be modified at runtime dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SessionFactoryImplementor sesionFactoryImplementor=(SessionFactoryImplementor)sessionFactory;

sesionFactoryImplementor.getNamedQuery("test").getQueryString();
```

Works with Hibernate 4. As Nayan Wadekar, commented you can not modify it at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, but I can create a new query from the string `Session.createSQLQuery(String)`

Comment: You can create a new query, but you also will need to reset params and perhaps other query details.

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me:

```
Query query = em.createNamedQuery(namedQuery);
String hql = query.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).getQueryString();
```

Hope this helps!